# User group in joomla 3.2.1

Tags: php, user, user-groups

Please help me. I have a problem about user group in joomla 3.2.1.
I created a new user group(name: Hoa Si) then i create a new user(abc) for Hoa Si group. But i can not login with new user(abc) on front end. But if i change the new user(abc) to any group in user group then login successfull to front end. New user group create: USER GROUP MANAGER -> NEW -> Group Title *: Hoa Si ; Group Parent *: Public. Thanks advance!

Comment: In your Global Configuration, set error reporting to maximum, then try logging in again to see if any errors are shown. I would also recommend you update your site to Joomla 3.3.1 as it's the latest stable version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the Group parent to registered (or any other than Public, Guest). As users from Public usergroup are not allowed to login at website.

Or you need to change the permissions of your newly created usergroup.

Comment: @hoangdung : Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not only creating a new user group, but also what **Permissions** and access the users in a user group will have. If you have set your user group as a child of the **Public** user group, then it won't have Site login permissions.

You should either go in the **Global Configuration** -> **Permissions** and assign to it the right permissions, "**Site Login**" and only for simple front-end login (registered users), or set this usergroup as a **child of** the **Registered** user group, in order to **inherit** its permissions.