# Menu Module not appearing/working with ACL

Tags: administration, acl, positions

I have a user menu namely X and it is assigned to a module.

I have also created a user group and a user access level. Then I assigned the user access level to the user group that I have created, namely Y. However, when I assign the user access level on the module, the module is not shown for me (On an account that I have created, and I have assigned the user group to it).

Where did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Otherwise the module is displayed?

Comment: Did you assign a module position?

Comment: I followed your instructions (plus assigned a module position), and it worked for me, however I changed the order.  First I confirmed that the module displayed when the access level was the default (public).  Then I assigned an access level and confirmed that the module disappeared.  Then I added the "test" group to the user and confirmed that the module appeared.  However, I needed to log out / log in between changes in group assignments.

Comment: @FFrewin yes if the user's group is registered only then it can be viewed, however when I set it to "registered and Y" or "Y" only then it cannot be viewed.

Comment: @PeterWiseman Yes I assigned a module position to it. Why isn't it working for me D':

Comment: @alinisme I tried with single and double combinations of groups. Works for me. Why would your module show when your user is only assigned the "Registered" group, and I'm assuming your "Registered" group isn't assigned the new access level.  Have you tried with a a fresh installation of Joomla for comparison?  Failing that, my next level of troubleshooting is to add some debug statements in the code, or using a debugger, but both are a lot of work.

Comment: @PeterWiseman Thanks for your replies, I will try redo this on a fresh installation of joomla ;

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't mess with anything deeper and assuming it is a casual joomla installation with your ACL additions, then it is definitely something you have not done right or ignoring in setting up your usergroup and access level.

It can be any combination of if your usergroup is or is not a child of other usergroup, and that while registered usergroup has viewing access to your Custom Access Level, your custom Usergroup has not. Add in the mix that the menu items of your menu might have also ACL settings and depending on the layout of the Module, the module will not be displayed at all, if there is no access to its content.

Make a step back from the website and read a bit the documentation about implementing ACL in Joomla, in order to get a better understanding.

- [Joomla ACL Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial)
- [Implementing Role-Based ACL](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-sept-2012/item/856-implementing-role-based-acl)
- Also this [JSE question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/user-group-in-joomla-3-2-1/3547#3547) deals with a similar issue and you might
  find useful answers:

I would suggest to start your experimentation with the Joomla ACL slowly, doing small changes and testing what is working and why, as it can be really confusing and easily a website can become messy.

Comment: Alright, I will try this, thank you very much!

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause of your issue? If so, you could post it here.